# permanently closing off a crawl space under a house

Tags: foundation, drainage

I have a old small house that that was built in the 60s above ground with a dirt  crawl space underneath. There are two  access openings on each side of the house 28 x 18. There is no need to crawl underneath the house,Under the wood floor are Abs drain lines & a few copper water pipes. I would like to re-stucco the  whole house and close off the openings with the new foam board and stucco to make it more attractive looking. Any reason I shouldn't stucco over the openings?? The house is located in the Phoenix Arizona. Your thoughts would be greatly appreciate it....

Comment: Yeah, right, plumbing never needs to be repaired, and other fictions...good luck with that.

Comment: @Ecnerwal while I agree on the general sentiment, both where I used to live and where I do live its pretty common to embed plumbing in the concrete pad, rendering it as equally inaccessible (even more so infact, as you can always make an access hole in a raised floor in the OPs example, cant do that trivially for a poured concrete pad) and no one bats an eyelid at that...  Indeed, in my current house, crawlspace access is internal to the property (hatch in the laundry room floor) and even then the plumber installing our second bathroom just made his own temporary access in that room.

Comment: @Ecnerwal is right: plumbing goes bad and needs access. My opinion is that it's foolish to deliberately wall it off and force yourself to do a complicated floor hatch in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The Code requires access to under floor space. (See ICC R408.3.)

If through the floor, it’s 18” x 24”, and if through a perimeter wall it’s 16” x 24”. If it’s below grade, then an areaway of not less than 16” x 24” is required.

Comment: Yikes,  your right. Thanks . Will go hunting for some  louver Gable Vents and stucco around them.  thanks again.....

Comment: that raises another issue, the crawlspace probably requires vents, but your gable vents will probably work fine for that.

Comment: @Jasen Gable vents in crawlspace?

Comment: @LeeSam as per roger's comment

Comment: If you prefer to have the outside closed off, put in the through-floor access.

Comment: His situation is pretty straightforward compared to many.  Being in the Phoenix area, it's unlikely he has a problem with ground moisture or high relative humidity in the air.